# How to use Multiple select statement in one jsp

Tags: sql-server, jsp-tags

Iam New in JSP actually i want to execute multiple Select query in JSP page Select query executed but only one if i try to write second select query it is not working giving me browser error connection refuse **just i want to know how can we use multiple select statement in one jsp** here is my below code

```
<%@page import="java.sql.SQLException"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.DriverManager"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.ResultSet"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.Statement"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.Connection"%>

<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>My First JSP Application in Net Beans</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Hello World! This is my First JSP web Page in Netbeans</h1>

        <h3>Todays Policy Count</h3>

        <%java.sql.Connection con;
java.sql.Statement state;
java.sql.ResultSet rs;
//java.sql.PreparedStatement pst;

con=null;
state=null;
//pst=null;
rs=null;

try
{
Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
String url="jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=Testing_DB;user=Atul;password=Pass@123";
con=DriverManager.getConnection(url);
state=con.createStatement();
//String sql="SELECT * FROM first_test";
String sql="select distinct gp.product_name,Count(1) as counting from gt_policy gp inner join gt_user_doc_recon dr on gp.alternate_policy_no=dr.udr_pol_no where gp.erp_intg_status is null group by gp.product_name";
rs=state.executeQuery(sql);
%>
<table border="1" width="10%">
    <tr>
        <th bgColor="Red"><font size="0.3"> <font color="Yellow"> product_name</font></font></th>
        <th bgColor="Red"><font size="0.3"> <font color="Yellow">counting</font></font></th>
    </tr>
    <% 
    while(rs.next())
    {
    %>
    <tr>
         <font size="2">
        <td>
            <%
            String product_name=rs.getString("product_name");
            String counting=rs.getString("counting");



            out.println(product_name);
            %> 
             <font size="2">
        </td>
        <td>
            <font size="2">
            <%
            //out.println(name);    
            out.println(counting);
            }
           %>
           </font>
        </td>


    </tr>

</table>

<%
    }
catch (ClassNotFoundException e)
    {
      e.printStackTrace();
      System.exit(1);
    }
    catch (SQLException e)
    {
      e.printStackTrace();
      System.exit(2);
    }


%>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is answer i got with out put

```
<%@page import="java.sql.SQLException"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.DriverManager"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.ResultSet"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.Statement"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.Connection"%>

<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>

<!DOCTYPE html>

    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>My First JSP Application in Net Beans</title>
    </head>

        <h1>Hello World! This is my First JSP web Page in Netbeans</h1>



        <%java.sql.Connection con;
java.sql.Statement state,state1,state2,state3;
java.sql.ResultSet rs,rs1,rs2,rs3;

//java.sql.PreparedStatement pst;

con=null;
state=null;
//pst=null;
rs=null;
rs1=null;
state1=null;
rs2=null;
state2=null;
rs3=null;
state3=null;

try
{
Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
String url="jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=Testing_DB;user=Atul;password=Pass@123";
//String url="jdbc:sqlserver://HOST:1433;DatabaseName=Testing_DB";
//String url="jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;databaseName=Testing_DB;";
con=DriverManager.getConnection(url);
state=con.createStatement();
state1=con.createStatement();
state2=con.createStatement();
state3=con.createStatement();

String sql="";
rs=state.executeQuery(sql);

String sql1="";
rs1=state1.executeQuery(sql1);

//
String sql2="";
rs2=state2.executeQuery(sql2);
//
//
//
String sql3="";
rs3=state3.executeQuery(sql3);




%>

  <div style="float: left; width:12%;">
       <h5>Todays Policy Count</h5>

<table border="1" width="10%">
    <tr>
        <th bgColor="Red"><font size="0.3"> <font color="Yellow"> product_name</font></font></th>
        <th bgColor="Red"><font size="0.3"> <font color="Yellow">counting</font></font></th>

    </tr>
    <% 
    while(rs.next())
    {
    %>
    <tr>
         <font size="2">
        <td>
            <%
            String product_name=rs.getString("product_name");
            String counting=rs.getString("counting");





            out.println(product_name);
            %> 

        </td>
        <td>
            <font size="2">
            <%

            out.println(counting);
            }
           %>
           </font>
        </td>




    </tr>

</table>
           </div>


           <div style="float: left; width:12%;">
               <h5>SYNC REPORT</h5>
<table border="1" width="12%">
    <tr>
        <th bgColor="Red"><font size="0.3"> <font color="Yellow"> PUS_SYNC_DATE</font></font></th>
        <th bgColor="Red"><font size="0.3"> <font color="Yellow">STATUS</font></font></th>
        <th bgColor="Red"><font size="0.3"> <font color="Yellow">COUNT</font></font></th>
    </tr>
    <% 
    while(rs1.next())
    {
    %>
    <tr>
        <td>
         <font size="2">

            <%
            String PUS_SYNC_DATE=rs1.getString("PUS_SYNC_DATE");
            String STATUS=rs1.getString("STATUS");
            String COUNT=rs1.getString("COUNT");





            out.println(PUS_SYNC_DATE);
            %> 
        </td>

        <td>
            <font size="2">
            <%
            //out.println(name);    
            out.println(STATUS);

           %>
           </font>
        </td>


        <td>
            <font size="2">
            <%
            //out.println(name);    
            out.println(COUNT);
            }
           %>
           </font>
        </td>



    </tr>

</table>
           </div>



           <div style="float: RIGHT; width:71%;">
               <h5>SYNC WITH ID REPORT</h5>
<table border="1" width="50%">
    <tr>
        <th bgColor="Red"><font size="0.3"> <font color="Yellow"> PUS_SYNC_DATE</font></font></th>
        <th bgColor="Red"><font size="0.3"> <font color="Yellow">PUS_UD_USER_ID</font></font></th>
        <th bgColor="Red"><font size="0.3"> <font color="Yellow">PUS_SYNC_ERROR_DESC</font></font></th>
        <th bgColor="Red"><font size="0.3"> <font color="Yellow">STATUS</font></font></th>
    </tr>
    <% 
    while(rs2.next())
    {
    %>
    <tr>
        <td>
         <font size="2">

            <%
            String PUS_SYNC_DATE=rs2.getString("PUS_SYNC_DATE");
            String PUS_UD_USER_ID=rs2.getString("PUS_UD_USER_ID");
            String PUS_SYNC_ERROR_DESC=rs2.getString("PUS_SYNC_ERROR_DESC");
            String STATUS=rs2.getString("STATUS");





            out.println(PUS_SYNC_DATE);
            %> 
        </td>

        <td>
            <font size="2">
            <%
            //out.println(name);    
            out.println(PUS_UD_USER_ID);

           %>
           </font>
        </td>


        <td>
            <font size="2">
            <%
            //out.println(name);    
            out.println(PUS_SYNC_ERROR_DESC);

           %>
           </font>
        </td>

        <td>
            <font size="2">
            <%
            //out.println(name);    
            out.println(STATUS);
            }

           %>
           </font>
        </td>



    </tr>

</table>
           </div>


            <div style="position:absolute;top:0; right:0;">
               <h5>POLICY ACCEPTED </h5>
<table border="1" width="50%">
    <tr>
        <th bgColor="Red"><font size="0.3"> <font color="Yellow"> PRODUCT_NAME</font></font></th>
        <th bgColor="Red"><font size="0.3"> <font color="Yellow">ACCEPTED ON</font></font></th>
        <th bgColor="Red"><font size="0.3"> <font color="Yellow">ALTERNATE_POLICY_NO</font></font></th>

    </tr>
    <% 
    while(rs3.next())
    {
    %>
    <tr>
        <td>
         <font size="2">

            <%
            String PRODUCT_NAME=rs3.getString("PRODUCT_NAME");
            String ACCEPTED_ON=rs3.getString("udr_date");
            String ALTERNATE_POLICY_NO=rs3.getString("ALTERNATE_POLICY_NO");






            out.println(PRODUCT_NAME);
            %> 
        </td>

        <td>
            <font size="2">
            <%
            //out.println(name);    
            out.println(ACCEPTED_ON);

           %>
           </font>
        </td>


        <td>
            <font size="2">
            <%
            //out.println(name);    
            out.println(ALTERNATE_POLICY_NO);
            }
           %>
           </font>
        </td>



    </tr>

</table>
           </div>



<%
    }
catch (ClassNotFoundException e)
    {
      e.printStackTrace();
      System.exit(1);
    }
    catch (SQLException e)
    {
      e.printStackTrace();
      System.exit(2);
    }


%>
```

[image]